# Mocking MultiBlocProvider to test app functionality

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-bloc

So I was planning on testing my app's functionality, but I stumbled upon an interesting issue.

In the app's root, I have a `MultiBlocProvider` that provides a few Bloc instances to the rest of the app.

When testing the app, I want to mock these Bloc instances - to check different states.

Is that possible?

I thought of adding them as optional constructor parameters to `MyApp`, but it feels kinda hacky.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you're testing it properly there should be no need to do that:

If you need to test a sub-page you don't instantiate it via MyApp, but you create the sub-page as standalone and inject the blocs you need to run the page itself.

If you need to test MyApp and MultiBlocProvider's behavior you might wanna go with the parameter solution, that's a good approach.

To be honest, in my apps I tend to avoid using provider exactly because if this, it becomes harder and harder to test when your app scales and also to implement it, I'd suggest to take a singleton approach and have a look at get_it.

Comment: Interesting. I tried testing a sub-page that way but got an exception because the MediaQuery I used inside the sub-page relied on the root context, have you stumbled upon that issue?

I'll also have a look at get_it, thanks!

Comment: Could you post the snipper of your test?

Comment: It's pretty simple really - in the case of the failing test due to MediaQuery:

testWidgets('sample test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(const OnboardingScreen());
    expect(find.text(Texts.locationSelectionTitle), findsOneWidget);
  });